# Click event not triggering keyboard in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, events

I need some help with focusing an input field in iOS. The keyboard on my iPhone doesn't pop up when triggering the click event.

```
render: function() {

        //set title events
        this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').on('click', this.focusSetTitle);
        this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').on('touchstart', this.focusSetTitle);
        this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').on('blur', this.setTitle);
        this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').on('keypress', this.onEnterSetTitle);
    },


focusSetTitle: function() {
        this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').val('');
        this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').focus();
        this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').addClass('input-active');
        window.blinkingInputBoolean = true;
        $('.set-title-input input').fadeTo( 0, 1);
    },


onEnterSetTitle: function(ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
            this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').trigger('blur');
            this.$el.next().find('.set-title-input input').trigger("click");
            this.$el.next().find('.set-title-input input').trigger("touchstart");
        }
    },
```

Comment: Maybe you should be looking for focus on the input, instead of a click. Or a touch event. (Just a wild guess)

Comment: Forgot to mention the click event triggers a focus event.

Comment: Is the event handler for the `click` event being fired? Can you show us that code?

Comment: I added the rest of my code in the post. Please have a look.

Comment: I can't find any problems, except for a style tweak: Have a look at ["chaining"](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/) in jQuery.

Comment: Oke too bad, i'll try the chaining. Thanks anyway.